# Why my SQLite cannot create table ID column?

Tags: android, mysql, database, sqlite, android-studio

I am creating apps in android studio, I create a table to store user's **name, email, password**, and also user's **ID**. The user's name, email and password is passed through user's input, while the ID is generated by computer automatically, when I create a table for those information, the above 3 column works fine but the I cannot create user's ID column.

Here is my code in creating a database table:

```
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME ="contacts.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME ="contacts";
private static final String COLUMN_ID ="id";
private static final String COLUMN_NAME ="name";
private static final String COLUMN_EMAIL ="email";
private static final String COLUMN_PASS ="pass";
SQLiteDatabase db;
private static final String TABLE_CREATE = "create table contacts (id INTEGER primary key NOT NULL ," +
        "name text not null, email text not null, pass text not null);";

public DatabaseHelper(Context context){
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {  // create database
    db.execSQL(TABLE_CREATE);
    this.db = db;
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
    String query = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME;
    db.execSQL(query);
    this.onCreate(db);
}

public void insertContact(Contact c){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

    String query = "select * from contacts";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);

    int count = cursor.getCount();

     values.put(COLUMN_ID, count);
    values.put(COLUMN_NAME, c.getUser_name());
    values.put(COLUMN_EMAIL, c.getUser_email());
    values.put(COLUMN_PASS, c.getUser_password());

    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values); // insert into database
    db.close();
}

public String searchPass(String uname){
    db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    String query = "select uname, pass from " + TABLE_NAME;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()){
        do {
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if (a.equals(uname)){
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    return b;
}
```

When I am testing my app, I taped into "name =abc, email=abc, password=abc", it shows following issues:

> 07-12 15:26:27.621 7943-7943/com.example.haoch.myapplication
>   E/SQLiteLog: (1) 
>       table contacts has no column named id
>       07-12 15:26:27.625 7943-7943/com.example.haoch.myapplication 
>       E/SQLiteDatabase: Error inserting email=abc name=abc pass=abc id=0
>       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named 
>       id (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(email,name,pass,id) 
>       VALUES (?,?,?,?)

Comment: can you pls try values.put("id", count);

Comment: this is actually same, COLUMN_ID equals to "id"

Comment: It seems that you add id after the table creation. reinstall the app and then insert data again

Answer (score 0):

Have you changed the database structure? 
If this is the case, every time you change something on the database structure you have to increase the DB Version:

```
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
```

alternatively you can reinstall the app or or clear the app's data on the device

Comment: Note that OP has NPE problem in opUpgrade() so bumping the version alone won't work.